# Calculate the correct gutter

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to have several blocks with different default sizes. As I am using `justify-content: space-between;`, I can't (and don't want to) set the space between 2 elements with a fixed value, neither do I want to have that for my items. But there I am getting a bit in trouble when I have a width of my big element of 49% and my small one with 24.5% that (see the picture please):

[image]

This is the code I use:

```css
.container{
    margin:8vh 0;
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.media_child{
    background:cyan;
    width:49%;
    margin-top:15px;
}

.media_child_small{
    background:tomato;
    width:24.5%;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

How do I calculate the width correctly in a scenario like that and how would I do it if I had even more different width-sizes (25%, 33%, 50% and 75%)?

Comment: Instead of assigning flex children a `width`, use [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) and set `flex-grow:1` so elements can expand as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But in that situation I really need to set the width due to layout options to a specific width even if the content needs way less space (or more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `flex` value to let expand the children and then set a `min-width` and `max-width` **without** a fixed value for the `width` so the browser will do the calculation itself to fit each elements at the best.

Best is to give you an example to test and play with:

```css
body {
  counter-reset:divs;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
div {
  counter-increment:divs;
  padding:5px;
  border:solid;
  margin:5px;
  flex:1;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
}
div:before {
  content:'div N°'counter(divs)' class='attr(class);
}
.quart {
  min-width:23%;
  max-width:25%;
}
.quartx3 {
  min-width:74%;
  max-width:75%;
}
.third {
  min-width:30%;
  max-width:33.33%;
}
.thirdx2 {
  min-width:60%;
  max-width:66.66%;
}
```

```html
<div class="quart"></div>
<div class="quart"></div>
<div class="quart"></div>
<div class="quart"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
<div class="thirdx2"></div>
<div class="quartx3"></div>
<div class="quart"></div>
```

pen to play with and fork https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wjPjmM